# Recent chats xmpp android application

Tags: android

I am android developer. I am working on a Android application creating a Chat application. I am facing  a small issue in displaying the recent chats using XMPP service. How can i fetch the recent chats. Is there any inbuilt function that i can use to fetch the data in XMPP. I am newly working on XMPP concepts. Any ideas will be of great help to me.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

depending on your XMPP server, you might not be able to get the recent chats (because the server might not store them for too long).

You would be better off saving all the chats to an internal SQLite database, and retrieving them from there as you need them. A classic XMPP server is only guaranteed to keep messages that have not been delivered yet.